# Wordpress validation error display

Tags: jquery, validation, wordpress

In wordpress forms there is no inline validation to notify the user. The validation is server based and the form refreshes and then the error messages will be displayed on top of the form.

Is there any plugin to change this to a jquery based validation. I am searching for it and couldn't find  such plugin. Please advise. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You could use very popular [Contact Form 7 plugin](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/contact-form-7/) and then install [Jquery Validation For Contact Form 7](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/jquery-validation-for-contact-form-7/) plugin that adds jquery validation in contact form 7 forms.

**UPDATE:**

For validation of custom forms I found [this](http://www.javascript-coder.com/html-form/javascript-form-validation.phtml) Javascript form validation script.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. but I want it for wordpress default login registration and other customized registration form pages as well